# What is standard for GML?

Tags: wfs, references, gml

I'm pushing some GML data into a Web Feature Service. And I want to keep to the GML/WFS standards when pushing my data.

Could anyone point me towards a document that shows me this or a quick explanation towards it?

Comment: I assume you have read http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/gml and http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs

Comment: I've had a dig through it about a month ago, but its so hard going. Its a few hundred pages with a thousands of lines of text. Just if anyone knew it  off by heart could just put it into byte size form. But if not ill go have a fun read for the next week.

Comment: a more detailed answer will require examples of your data schemas

Comment: I would start by reading schemata from http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd.

Answer (score 1):

Something to be aware of if you are looking for a quick explanation is the [GML Simple Features Profile](http://www.ogcnetwork.net/gml-sf) which is used by software such as [ArcGIS for Desktop to consume WFS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00370000000m000000):

> The Open Geospatial Consortium, Inc.'s (OGC) Web Feature Service (WFS)
>   is a standard protocol for serving geographic features across the web.
>   The GIS feature information that is encoded and transported using WFS
>   includes both feature geometry and feature attribute values.
>
> The feature information in WFS is encoded using Geography Markup
>   Language (GML), which is used to express geographic information using
>   XML. The GML Simple Features profile is recommended for use with
>   ArcGIS and is the basis for WFS support in ArcGIS.